# Realm migration: suitable code structure and design pattern

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, realm, realm-migration

With the progress of an app, the realm migration is increased by a large volume. Is there any optimal design pattern which can significantly reduce the coding for migration? Suppose, I have the following migration:

```
if (!schema.contains(Subject.class.getSimpleName())) {
                            RealmObjectSchema inputConfigSchema = schema.create(Subject.class.getSimpleName())
                                    .addField("name", String.class)
                                    .addField("difficulty", String.class);

                            if (!schema.get(Student.class.getSimpleName()).hasField("subject")) {
                                schema.get(Student.class.getSimpleName()).addRealmObjectField("subject", inputConfigSchema);
                            }

                        }
                        if (!schema.get(Student.class.getSimpleName()).hasField("age")) {
                            schema.get(Student.class.getSimpleName()).addField("age", Integer.class);
                            schema.get(Student.class.getSimpleName()).setNullable("age", false);
                        }
    }
```

please suggest a suitable design pattern to optimize this type of realm migration

Answer (score 0):

Using `Student.class.getSimpleName()` to get the string `"Student"` will fail when:

- Proguard is used and the class is obfuscated
- If `Student` class is deleted from the project

.

```
RealmObjectSchema student = schema.get("Student")
if (!schema.contains("Subject")) {
    RealmObjectSchema subject = schema.create("Subject")
                                    .addField("name", String.class)
                                    .addField("difficulty", String.class);

    if (student.hasField("subject")) {
        student.addRealmObjectField("subject", subject);
    }
}

if (!student.hasField("age")) {
    student.addField("age", Integer.class, FieldAttributes.REQUIRED);
}
```